# MySQL order by not working in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to order records with respect to employees' name and their `checkin_date`s.
But the result is not as expected.
I have following stored procedure :

```
BEGIN

SELECT 
    concat(u.firstname,' ',u.lastname) as fullname, t.date_from as checkin_date, 
    t.date_to as checkout_date, t.delayed_checkin_remarks, t.early_checkout_remarks, t.leave_remarks, t.leave_status, t.checkin_time, t.checkout_time
FROM
    users u
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT user_id as id, DATE(leave_from) as date_from, DATE(leave_to) as date_to, 
        NULL as checkin_time, NULL as checkout_time,
        NULL as delayed_checkin_remarks, NULL as early_checkout_remarks, 
        CONCAT(' <u>LeaveType : ', (
            SELECT title 
            FROM leave_type
            WHERE id = l.leave_type_id),
            '</u><br/>', leave_description) as leave_remarks, leave_status
    FROM users_leave_request l 
    WHERE DATE(leave_from) between date(start_date) AND date(end_date) 
       OR DATE(leave_to) BETWEEN date(start_date) AND date(end_date)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT users_id as id, DATE(checkin_time) as date_from, DATE(checkout_time) as date_to, 
        TIME(checkin_time) as checkin_time, TIME(checkout_time) as checkout_time,
        delayed_checkin_remarks, early_checkout_remarks, NULL as leave_remarks, NULL as leave_status
    FROM checkin_checkout
    WHERE DATE(checkin_time) between date(start_date) AND date(end_date) 
       OR DATE(checkout_time) BETWEEN date(start_date) AND date(end_date)
    ) as t
  ON (u.id = t.id)
ORDER by fullname, checkin_date;

END
```

But the result is not as expected :

```
Jack  | 2015-01-23 | 09:00:49 |
Jack  | 2015-01-30 | 09:00:49 |
Jack  | 2015-01-26 | 09:00:49 |
Jack  | 2015-01-27 | 09:00:49 |
```

When not in stored procedure, I think it was outputting desired result-set.

Comment: @shA.t how do you mean? please can  you show it how?

Comment: My guess is that fullname is not the same even though it looks the same.

Comment: @P.Salmon the result is working fine, I think,except for that ordering

Comment: I notice that you have 2 date ordered blocks of Jack hence my comment.

Comment: What is your query result with out using SP? I think it should [work fine](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57140/1) ;).

Comment: yeah... it was as expected...